# Can drip edge be affixed using adhesive?

Tags: adhesive, roofing, gutters, flashing

I need to replace my drip edge on a low pitch modified bitumen roof. The edge is about 13' long and I had to rip the old one cause it was deformed and not working right. Under it is a sheet of what looks like bitumen sheeting and under that 1x lumber (for roof sheathing before plywood) quite old and not always holding fasteners well cause of decay. I could try to drill pilot holes in both the flashing and roof but in case that doesn't hold too well, can I just glue it using something like Liquid Nails? The drip edge should be 3"x3"x13'.

Comment: I hate to complicate your situation but if the wood is so decayed that it cannot hold fasteners it will do a lousy job of holding onto a construction adhesive. All the decayed wood needs to be replaced. And from the sounds of it the roof material also probably needs removal and replacement as well so that you can inspect and replace any and all of the roof boards that are rotten and decayed. And since a drip edge is supposed to be installed before the roof shingles this would also be the sane time to replace the drip edge.

Comment: I stated my main point in the first sentence. Decayed wood will not do a good job of holding the adhesive.

Comment: Adhesive is not adequate for holding on a drip edge. It must be held on with a mechanical fastener i.e. roofing nails. I suppose you can put a thin bead of construction adhesive on for added support, but it can't be used alone. If you didn't nail it on, the drip edge would just fall off before the adhesive cured completely.

Comment: Since the drip edge will slide up under shingles, wouldn't the adhesive stick to the shingles?  It could be considered a shingle extender.  PS:  proper installation leaves space between the fascia and drip edge...don't put it tight against the fascia.

Answer (score 1):

I found this on a site referencing common roofing mistakes.  It confirms that the flashing can be held in place by adhesives.

4. Neglecting to install drip edge flashing at the eaves

The missing of drip edge flashings can cause several problems at the bottom of a roof, because these flashings serve a number of purposes:
Drip edge flashings keep insects out of the attic.
They prevent wind-driven rain from entering under the edge of the roof.
They provide a “drip point” for water to drip off from the roof which helps prevent soffit or fascia rot.
They keep shingles from “sagging” as they extend past the edge of the roof.

Solution:

If necessary, pop up roofing nails from the shingles and slide in a metal flashing. Glue the flashing and shingles with bituminous mastic.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the site where this was found?

Comment: Of course you can glue metal to wood. That was never really in doubt. The question is whether it will effectively hold metal to _decaying_ wood. This answer doesn't address that.